# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Inchoo_Notes_Helper_Data'

Tags: magento-1.9

I run Magento 1.9.3.x and in the process of cleaning up old modules not in use anymore I disabled **Inchoo Notes**, after this I got errors... I googled help online help  and was recommended to delete files and records from the database.

Now I ended up with Fatal error:

```
Class 'Mage_Inchoo_Notes_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/domain.dk/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547 showing when I enter /system_config/...
```

Even more weird if i disable, another module; `Inchoo_FeaturedProducts.xml` (true to false) the fatal error is gone and I can use `/system_config/` again... but, I am using **Inchoo FeaturedProducts** module to display products on the frontpage... so that is not a doable solution.

Any ideas what to do here ?

Thanks.

Comment: check system.xml files of the all the modules which are having Inchoo as Namespace

Comment: I have 123 system.xml files... only one of them contains "inchoo"... located at \app\code\community\Inchoo\FeaturedProducts\etc

Comment: The first few lines are:     <tabs>
        <inchoo module="inchoo_notes">
            <label>Inchoo</label>
            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
        </inchoo>
    </tabs>

Comment: Replace `inchoo_notes` with `Inchoo_FeaturedProducts`

Comment: is Compilation is On ?

Comment: Tried the edits... empty cache, compilation is deactivated... I manually decompiled... log out, logged in... deleted /var/cache/... still the same problem...

Comment: Can you update your config.xml and system.xml to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `inchoo_notes` with `Inchoo_FeaturedProducts`

```
<tabs> <inchoo module="Inchoo_FeaturedProducts"> <label>Inchoo</label> <sort_order>110</sort_order> </inchoo> </tabs>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Accept the answer by pressing right icon. Upvote the answer

Comment: I would love to - but the issue is not solved... Tried the edits... empty cache, compilation is deactivated... I manually decompiled... log out, logged in... deleted /var/cache/... still the same problem...

Comment: I ended up outcommenting the <tabs> section - problem solved!